# Why does my function, that fills a textarea, only work the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript:

```
function editQuestion() {
  $("body").on("click", ".edit_question", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("form").find("textarea").text("sample text");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
  editQuestion();
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <textarea>ormar</textarea>
  <div class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="edit_question">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

When firing off the function by clicking the `.edit_question` link, everything is working as expected the first time.

But clicking more times (after manually removing the textarea content) doesn't do anything, why is this?

Comment: Where is element with `.edit_question` ?

Comment: @shaunakde I'm sorry, a typo in the question. Now corrected. The problem is still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.text()` only changes the *initial* value of the textarea, since the initial value is read from the element's content (`<textarea>Initial value</textarea>`).

Once you modified the value, the current value is stored in the `value` property of the DOM element. Changing the initial value after the textarea was modified doesn't have any effect.

That's why you should use [**`.val()`**](https://api.jquery.com/val/) intead of `.text()`.

Comment: @sudharsan: Not for me. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/ktPe3/ with http://jsfiddle.net/ktPe3/1/. Modify the value, then click the link. And too all downvoters, maybe you should run the code yourself before you jump to conclusions.

Comment: Again .text() working as same as .val() in your fiddle.Still there is no difference between .val() and .text()

Comment: @sudharsan: You modified the value before you clicked the link, yes?

Comment: @sudharsan not, they're not

Answer (score 1):

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GArTz/1/)  compare with **[Original Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GArTz/2/)**

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in case of inputs.

Check this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".edit_question", function (event) {

        $(this).closest("form").find("textarea").val('sample text');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Note:** The [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .val() method rather than .text() method for textarea

**From documentation page:**
The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

**link:** http://api.jquery.com/text/